# Count how many times one post has been read

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to show how many times one post has been read? In WordPress there is a plug-in,https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/

I don't know whether there is such a plug-in in Anypic of Parse to count the times?

Of course it will be nice if it can display who has read a post as well.

Thanks

Comment: You can add a readCount column and just increment it every time someone opens it. I don't know what operating system you need an example of but parse docs has great tutorials on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language you working on.

But anyway you need to create:

- Array column in Parse.com

And then just make query to add his name when viewWillAppear

Now you can count the array to get integer number for views and you can display their names from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Two options are;

1. Add a `viewcount` column and increment it whenever needed.
2. Add an `actions` table which consist all actions within your webpage or app. This way you can store more data(custom analytics) in it like button pressing etc.. When you want to check the viewcount you can just count objects with specific type. For iOS SDK `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` does this job.